# What is the difference between Object name and display name in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory

I'm new to Active Directory, I created a user account using `dsadd` user command, later I tried to change the user account's display name, but the object name didn't change as in the screenshot:

[image]

So what is the difference between these two names?

And how can I change the object name/rename it using `dsmod user` command ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call the "object name" is called the Common Name (the `cn` attribute on the account). The CN makes up part of the `distinguishedName` (or DN), which uniquely identifies the object. Since the DN is made up of the CN and the OU, the CN must be unique in the OU.

The `displayName` does not need to be unique at all. This is the name that is seen by users. For example, this is what Outlook will show to users.

To change the CN at the command line, you actually need to use [`dsmove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc731094(v=ws.11)). That documentation gives an example:

> To rename a user object from Kim Akers to Kim Ralls, type:
>
> `dsmove "CN=Kim Akers,OU=Sales,DC=Contoso,DC=Com" -newname "Kim Ralls"`